# SVN Ignore on committed directories

Tags: svn, ignore

I didn't use SVN for a while as git is much better for my needs. Now I have to. I have run into a problem, I have committed .idea directory into the project, which has overwritten idea's config's to other repo committers. They have resolved it by placing their own config's elsewhere and left those files in the directory. 
I do not wish to commit my config to the repo, I want to ignore it. My concern is: what will happen to those files if add them to the svn:ignore property.

1. will they get deleted locally
2. Will they get deleted in other user's working copies?

Is there a way to do a dry-run?

Comment: And one last question, does the ignore property get committed to other users?

Comment: Should someone need it: ignore is only local and it is not being pushed to the repository, as I have been told

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, as with Git, Subversion or any other modern version-control system, you should place ignores when starting the project. This could help you avoid this problem.

> My concern is: what will happen to those files if add them to the
>   svn:ignore property.

Nothing. Ignores affect unversioned items only. You have to remove the committed files from the repository's HEAD revision and add `svn:ignore` pattern.

> Will they get deleted localy

They will not be deleted automatically. You should run `svn remove --keep-local <PATH>`.

> Will they get deleted in other user's working copies?

Yes, they will be deleted the next time they run `svn update.

Don't forget to read the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html).